# How to cache static file css in Nodejs Express?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Im using express-ejs-layouts to cache any file css but not cached. When i not use express-ejs-layouts in project but fine. Any idea !

Comment: add code and what have you tried?

Comment: I found the answer in nginx . Thanks !

Comment: @Newpie You should probably delete this question as your solution seems unrelated to your original question.